# Angular How to refresh data in observable on click

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs-observables

I am trying to refresh my data from my Observable on click

Here is my code
My Parent Component

```js
export class StepComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['dateCreation','siteName', 'adress'/*,'enseigne'*/, 'postCode', 'commune','prestation', 'validation'];

  dataset! : DataTable[];

  @ViewChild(ButtonComponent) bhuttonChild!: ButtonComponent;

  constructor(private dataTableService : DataTableService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataTableService.fetchDataTableNewPrestation().subscribe(r => this.dataset = r); // I would like to refresh this data with the event of the buttonChild

  }
}
```

step.html ( the parent component)

```html
<table class="table" mat-table [dataSource]="dataset">
[...]

      <ng-container matColumnDef="validation">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Validation </th>
        <mat-cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <app-button [element]="element"></app-button>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

Here my child component which is a buttoon :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  template: `
      <div  *ngIf="element.id"  >
        <button mat-raised-button [value]="false" (click)="initTaskOnPrestation(false)" color="primary">Normal</button>
        <button mat-raised-button [value]="true" (click)="initTaskOnPrestation(true)" color="warn">Urgent</button>
      </div>

  `,
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss']
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() element!: Prestation;
  urgent!: boolean

  @Input() lastStatus!: number;
  statusHistory!: StatusHistory;

  @ViewChild('button')
  button!: ElementRef;

  constructor(private taskService : TaskService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  initTaskOnPrestation(bool : boolean){
    this.prestation.urgency = bool;
    this.taskService.initTaskOnPrestation(this.prestation);
  }

}
```

My button is charged to send a request who will change my data in my backend but then I need to reload the data from my StepComponent with the `fetchDataTableNewPrestation()` method.

I am trying to get button event to use it, but I don't know how to do it even after check many time the the [Rxjs documentation](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Output` to inform the parent component that data needs to be reloaded:

In child component:

```
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Output() dataChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  initTaskOnPrestation(bool : boolean){
    this.prestation.urgency = bool;
    this.taskService.initTaskOnPrestation(this.prestation);
    this.dataChanged.emit(this.prestation);
  }
}
```

In parent component HTML:

```
<mat-cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <app-button [element]="element" (dataChanged)="reloadData($event)"></app-button>
 </mat-cell>
```

In parent component typescript:

```
export class StepComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reloadData();
  }
  reloadData() {
    this.dataTableService.fetchDataTableNewPrestation().subscribe(r => this.dataset = r);
  }
}
```